# Has Cassian Andor ever been captured and tortured by the Empire before Rogue One?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

[This article](https://www.inverse.com/article/24870-rogue-one-star-wars-cassian-andor-facts) from Inverse.com states the following:

> [Diego] Luna said he spent a night camping with former Marines and Navy to research the role [of Cassian]. Specifically, he wanted to learn about what it's
>   like to be captured and tortured, because Andor has been captured in the past.

EDIT: It seems like the Inverse article summarizes this [Slashfilm interview](http://www.slashfilm.com/rogue-one-diego-luna-interview/), where Diego Luna says "Cassian has been captured more than once".

Has this element of backstory ever been mentioned elsewhere?

Answer (score 5):

### **Yes and no.**

There aren't any specifics given, but the fact that he's been subjected to Imperial torture ***at some point*** is definitely part of the official canon.

> *The fledgling Rebel Alliance relies heavily on covert operatives to
> stymie Imperial operations. These strikes are discreet and targeted.
> Acts of sabotage, espionage and even assassinations fill Andor's
> casefile. **Knowing from experience the efficacy of Imperial
> interrogation,** Andor respects the need for secrets to be kept from
> field agents. He remains active to stave off the downtime that would
> plunge him into deeper reflection on some of his most extreme
> assignments.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Rogue One - The Ultimate Visual Guide](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Rogue_One:_The_Ultimate_Visual_Guide)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

### Maybe

There is a sentence in the Rogue One novelization:

> The last time Cassian has hurt so bad, K-2SO had carried him to a safe house and along the way enumerated his every injury, thoroughly assessed the likelihoods of infection and permanent nerve damage. -ch 22.

So maybe K-2SO rescued him from such a situation, but that is something of a leap.

We know he has a knowledge of Imperial interrogation techniques, whether it is first hand or not we don't know.

> The informant let out one last little groan, like he'd been troubled in his sleep, and lay still. *They would've caught you, Tivik. You would've broken. You would've died. And neither of us would deliver your message.* -ch 1.

After Princess Leia's interrogation, she was scheduled to be executed. I suspect that is the norm, and that few people go through an interrogation session and live to tell about it.